# как удалить элемент со списка

Tags: javascript

после добавления элементов в список, при клике на какой-то элемент нужно удалить его.

Буду признателен если подскажете как можно это реализовать.

Если я правильно понимаю, у меня одна из главных проблем что removeItem не вызывается, когда элементы добавлены в список

```js
(function() {

  "use strict"

  let List = {
    items: [],
    init: function() {
      this.casheDom();
      this.bindEvent();
      this.removeItem();
    },
    casheDom: function() {
      this.input = document.querySelector(".js-input");
      this.button = document.querySelector(".js-btn-add");
      this.view = document.querySelector(".js-list-view");
      this.listItem = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
    },
    bindEvent: function() {
      this.button.addEventListener("click", this.addItem.bind(this));
    },
    render: function() {
      this.clearList();
      let arr = this.items;
      for (let i = 0; arr.length > i; i++) {
        let elem = document.createElement("div"),
          itemTxt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
        elem.setAttribute("class", "item");
        elem.appendChild(itemTxt);
        this.view.appendChild(elem);
      }
      this.listItem = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
    },
    addItem: function() {
      this.items.push(this.input.value);
      this.render();
      this.input.value = '';
    },
    removeItem: function() {
      let elems = this.listItem;
      console.log(elems);
      for (let i = 0; elems.length > i; i++) {
        elems[i].onclick = function() {
          //remove item
        }
      }
    },
    clearList: function() {
      let myNode = this.view;
      while (myNode.firstChild) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
      }
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    List.init();
  });
})();
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <input type="text" class="js-input">
  <button class="js-btn-add">add</button>
  <div class="js-list-view"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeItem` вызывается только внутри `Init`. В этот момент `this.listItem` еще пустой массив, так как нет никаких элементов.

Из-за этого обработчики никуда не навешиваются.

Простым решением вместо `removeItem`, который бежит по всем элементам, можно сделать `removeItem`, который добавляет обработчик конкретному элементу:

```
removeItem: function(elem) {
  elem.onclick = function() {
    console.log(elem);
  }
},
```

Для удаления можно воспользоваться методом [`.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

```js
(function() {

  "use strict"

  let List = {
    items: [],
    init: function() {
      this.casheDom();
      this.bindEvent();
    },
    casheDom: function() {
      this.input = document.querySelector(".js-input");
      this.button = document.querySelector(".js-btn-add");
      this.view = document.querySelector(".js-list-view");
      this.listItem = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
    },
    bindEvent: function() {
      this.button.addEventListener("click", this.addItem.bind(this));
    },
    render: function() {
      this.clearList();
      let arr = this.items;
      for (let i = 0; arr.length > i; i++) {
        let elem = document.createElement("div"),
          itemTxt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
        elem.setAttribute("class", "item");
        elem.appendChild(itemTxt);
        this.view.appendChild(elem);
        this.removeItem(elem);
      }
      this.listItem = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
    },
    addItem: function() {
      this.items.push(this.input.value);
      this.render();
      this.input.value = '';
    },
    removeItem: function(elem) {
      elem.onclick = function() {
        console.log(elem);
        elem.remove();
      }
    },
    clearList: function() {
      let myNode = this.view;
      while (myNode.firstChild) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
      }
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    List.init();
  });
})();
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <input type="text" class="js-input">
  <button class="js-btn-add">add</button>
  <div class="js-list-view"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: тут возникает проблема, когда например добавлено 5 елементов, я удалая 2 из них, а потом я снова добавляю то возвращаються старые елементы, как можно это поправить?

Comment: @DimaVleskov, конечно можно. Кроме удаления самого элемента, удаляй его и из массива `items`

Comment: спасибо, понял.